# Add more dropdown box menu using javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I need to add more copies of my drop down box on the html everytime I click the "add" button and I can only do this for 5 times.

---

```
function AddVCD()
{
    var cdcounter = 0;
    var opt = document.createElement('option');

    document.getElementById("vcdchoice").innerhtml("Pitch Perfect");
    document.getElementById("vcdchoice").innerhtml("500 Days of Summer");
    document.getElementById("vcdchoice").innerhtml("The Notebook");
    document.getElementById("vcdchoice").innerhtml("The Vow");
    document.getElementById("vcdchoice").innerhtml("Lincoln");


    cdcounter++;
}
```

This is my code for the drop down box to be duplicated whenever I click a button

---

```
<select id = "vcdchoice">
      <option value="movie1">Movie1</option>
      <option value="movie2">Movie2</option>
      <option value="movie3">Movie3</option>
      <option value="movie4">Movie4</option>
      <option value="movie5">Movie5 </option>
    </select>
```

This is the code of my button.

---

```
     <button type = "button" id = "addVCD" onclick="AddVCD()"> ADD ANOTHER VCD     </button>
```

I think there is something wrong with my javascript. Yep, definitely.

Comment: I agree, **definitely**.

Comment: What does the JS do? I noticed that in the first snippet, you don't ask for the specific `option` element, just for `vcdchoice`. This might result in the `innerHTML` of the `select` with ID `vcdchoice` being replaced 5 times until it becomes `"Lincoln"` and obliterates all the `option`s--**definitely** undesirable.

Comment: I hope what it will do is to add 5 more drop down menu for me whenever I click the ADD ANOTHER VCD button, the same ones as my dropdown code given there.